# How to call a method in another view model

Tags: swift, mvvm, swiftui

I'm new to SwiftUI/MVVM architecture and would like to seek your kind help.

I have ViewModelA and ViewModelB.
When an API call succeeds in ViewModelA, I want to call functionA in ViewModelA and functionB in ViewModelB.

Calling the former functionA succeeds, but the latter functionB fails.

```
class ViewModelA: ObservableObject {

    @ObservedObject var viewModelB = ViewModelB()

    func updateTokens() {
      //runs API call. Write below inside closure

      functionA()
      viewModelB.functionB()   
 }

    func functionA(){
}
}
```

```
class ViewModelB: ObservableObject {
  func fetchMySentAnswers() {
  //This is the functionB in the example
  //runs API call
}
}
```

By the way I'm instantiating ViewModelB in another View as well, so there are two ViewModelB instantiated objects.

```
struct ViewB: View {
 @ObservedObject var viewModelB = ViewModelB()
}
```

(Basically I access the view models from views only because I've haven't seen communication between view models in SwiftUI tutorials. Please let me know if you shouldn't do this.)

Comment: I think you want a third class that communicates with the api and that your view model can use to access the fetched data.

Comment: Also, `@ObservedObject` only works in view structs, and it will only update if you have an `@Published` variable in your `ObservableObject`.

Comment: Joakim, thanks for your comment. What I have learned is, View Model communicates with the API and fetches the data, then put it in the Model, which is owned by the View Model, access that from the View. That works without issues, but in my specific case I want to access View Model from View Model.

Comment: Yrb, thanks for your comment. I didn't know that @ObservedObject only works in view structs. Then how can I call ViewModelA's functionB() when updateTokens() in View ModelA completes? Maybe publish isComplete parameter to View from ViewModelA and call ViewModelB's functionB() from that View?

Comment: The main point is that view models should not depend on or communicate with each other and there is nothing stoping you from adding other classes, services or controllers as they are called, to your app that can hold data or have functionality shared by many view models.

Comment: Joakim, thanks. Understood that the view models should not communicate with each other. Are you suggesting to move the functionB() which does the API call to a new Class and access that Class from ViewModelA? That seems like nothing has truly changed (i.e: name of ViewModelA just changed to Class xxx)

Comment: Joakim, I did some study and understood what you meant. Sorry and thanks!